# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many presence validation never passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a many to many relation between answers and replies for a poll app. Each poll has many submissions and each submission can have many replies. So i am using accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies in my submission form allowing multiple replies from a user. The problem is validating the collection of checkboxes answers(options) in the nested form as i always get a blank error. It never lets me pass the validation unless i get rid of it, which saves the data correctly. Any idea whats going on?

### submission.rb

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :poll
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :replies, inverse_of: :submission, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies
end
```

### answer.rb

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question, inverse_of: :answers
  has_and_belongs_to_many :replies

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2, maximum: 150 }
end
```

### reply.rb

```
class Reply < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :submission, inverse_of: :replies
  has_and_belongs_to_many :answers

  validates :raiting_field, presence: true, allow_nil: true

  validates :answers, presence: true
end
```

### submissions_controller.rb

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_poll, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @submission = Submission.new
    @poll.questions.each do
      @submission.replies.build
    end
  end

  def create
    @submission = Submission.new(submission_params)
    @submission.poll = @poll
    @submission.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @submission.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@poll.client, :polls],
          flash: { success: "The survey has been submitted successfully."}}
        format.js   {}
        format.json {
          render json: @submission, status: :created, location: @submission
        }
      else
        format.html { render 'new' }
        format.js   {}
        format.json {
          render json: @submission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def set_poll
    @poll = Poll.find(params[:poll_id])
  end

  def submission_params
    params.require(:submission).permit(replies_attributes: [:raiting_field, :question_id, answer_ids:[]])
  end
end
```

### _field.html.haml

```
= f.hidden_field :question_id, value: @submission.poll.question.id
= f.association :answers,
  collection: @submission.poll.answers,
  as: :check_boxes, label: false, include_hidden: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes include a blank entry so as to ensure that some response always comes back (if you unchecked all entries but nothing came back, the persisted list would not be changed and what was checked would remain checked).

So set your `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to ignore the blank records.

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies, reject_if: :all_blank
```

Comment: That wont work. It stills seems to be a blank value. I also tried setting include_hidden: false in the checkbox to remove blank values and it doesnt work either